# Move div and banner without them separating?

Tags: html, css

I created a contact form with a banner at the top of it. I created the entire thing and was planning on moving it to the right, off the screen, so that it will slide onto the screen when it is hovered over. I intended to just wrap a div around all of it and then relatively position it and move it however far I needed it to go to the right to be off the screen. However, when I tried to do this, it made the banner and the contact form box, as well as everything inside of those two elements, show up in a bunch of different random spots around the screen. I figured this was because it applied the relative positioning, as well as the `left:100px` value I set with it, to every element within the div and that, mixed with the other positioning I had set for each object, caused the weird displacements? Does anyone know how I can move the form and the banner so that they stay attached to each other and everything inside stays where it is?

Here's the JSFiddle where I set up the contact form box and banner: **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh1k4mm8/)**

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of your code.

Comment: You should hide your e-mail, if you don't want spam from bots.

Comment: Forgot I left that in there, thanks

Comment: The Mail is still visible when you click on "edited x mins ago", even for not logged in guests... I don't know how to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure about all your absolute and relative positioning insde of your form - if you dont want to place the elements at **very** specific points you wouldnt need this.

here's a jsfiddle for what i think you want to have:
https://jsfiddle.net/spmhxteu/

basically you will need to set this for your email wrap

```
position: absolute;
right: -200px;
```

and you should set this for your body or whatever is wrapped around

```
overflow: hidden;
width: 800px; // example
```

all elements INSIDE your absolute positioned div do not have to be relative or absolute again.

UPDATE: As requested here an absolute positioning inside the element:
https://jsfiddle.net/spmhxteu/1/

Note: Ofcourse your padding etc. of the parent div will not apply on absolute positioning

Comment: How would I go about positioning them precisely then?

Comment: if you want them to be relative to your absolute positioned wrap you would also use position: absolute; not relative - i ll update the answer with a second js fiddle including this